# Code to Find the Merge Point of Two linked Lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Forward Declaration of FindMergePoint()

```
int FindMergePoint(Node *Larger,int largeCount,Node *Smaller,int SmallCount);
```

Function which will count the length of both lists the according to the size passes the lists to FindMergePoint() which will return the node of intersection.

```
    int FindMergeNode(Node *headA, Node *headB)
    {
        Node *PTRA = headA;
    Node *PTRB = headB;
    int count1 = 0,count2 = 0;
    //Count List One
    while(PTRA != NULL){
        count1++;
        PTRA = PTRA->next;
    }
    //Count List Two
    while(PTRB != NULL){
        count2++;
        PTRB = PTRB->next;
    }
    //If First list is greater
    if(count1 >= count2){
        return FindMergePoint(headA,count1,headB,count2);
    }
    else{//Second is greater
        return FindMergePoint(headB,count2,headA,count1);
    }
}
```

Function Which Takes Larger and Smaller Lists and Finds the merge Point

```
 int FindMergePoint(Node *Larger,int largeCount,Node *Smaller,int SmallCount){
    Node *PTRL = Larger;
    //Now traversing till both lists have same length so then we can move 
parallely in both lists
    while(largeCount != SmallCount){
        PTRL = PTRL->next;
        largeCount--; 
    }
    Node *PTRS = Smaller;
    //Now PTRL AND PTRS WERE SYNCHRONIZED
    //Now,Find the merge point     
    while(PTRL->next != PTRS->next){
        PTRL = PTRL->next;
        PTRS = PTRS->next;
    }
    return PTRL->data;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a debugger and drawing the lists as you single step through the code.

Comment: You are the one who is supposed to figure out what is wrong with the code. Does it not compile? Does it not link? What is the error message? Does it crash? Which line? Does it produce incorrect results? Which results did it produce and which did you expect? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Were you permitted to destroy the structure of the original lists?

Comment: It's really unclear what a merge is in your context. What will the user of this do with the merge point?

Comment: Is this a merge or a merge sort?

Comment: Merge here means these lists have point of intersection after that both have same nodes like a fork

Comment: We have to find the point of intersection of these lists

Comment: @nwp it compiled, but I am not getting the correct answer!!

Comment: @drescherjm Yes we just have to find that intersection and that's it.

Comment: Which values did you give to the function? Which answer did it give? Which answer would have been correct?

Comment: It also would help to have a working minimal example. This will include an `int main()` that merges 2 lists and outputs the result. For simplicity you probably only want to have a few items in each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code block at `FindMergeNode` is causing the problem

```
while(PTRL->next != PTRS->next) {
    PTRL = PTRL->next;
    PTRS = PTRS->next;
}
```

Let's say, we have the following entries for `PTRL` and `PTRS`

```
PTRL -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
PTRS -> 17 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
```

Now, according to your implementation, `PTRL` will move ahead **4 times**
 (length of smaller linked list) and will point to `5`. Then, your logic checks whether `next` of `PTRL`(which points to 6) is equal to `next` of `PTRS`(which points to 6). If they are equal (which they are, because both points to 6), the method returns `data` of `PTRL`, which is `5` at that point.

Change condition in while loop to `PTRL != PTRS` and I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: or I can return PTRL->next->data